# .NET 3.5 targeted application looks for .NET 4.0 assembly

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

I have written a desktop software which use internet as well. Sending Http Requests and Using Linq2Twitter library.

Software is targeted to /NET 3.5 and there is no assembly in references to be targeted as .NET 4.0

I tested it on several machines with different versions of windows successfully.

However, one of my clients reported that my software crashes, and from log file i found this :

```
 Could not load file or assembly 'System.ServiceModel.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,     PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

So, my question is, how this happen?
Why i can not see this issue in my side?

It works on a machine with only .NET 3.5 installed, so it shouldn't use .NET 4 assembly right?
Why it confuse on my client machine?

PS:  i dont use System.ServiceModel.Web in my software but apparently Linq2Twitter does, could that be the source of problem? (Im using .NET 3.5 version of Linq2Twitter by the way)

Can anyone help?
When i check references using Reflector or Telerik JustDecompile , i dont see any dependency to any .NET 4 assembly at all.

UPDATE:

Its weird, i got a more detailed log to help me find out the problem.
Looking at StrackTrace, this is the error message :

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.ServiceModel.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I logged Inner error as well, and here it is :

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.ServiceModel.Web, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

It seems its looking for 3.5.0.0 version at first, then 4.0.0.0 and then throw the error.

What can cause that? is that possible that some assemblies are missed!?

Comment: Reflect `Linq2Twitter` and see if they use `System.ServiceModel.Web`. May be your client reported the wrong log. Because you said yourself, "It works on a machine with only .NET 3.5 installed". Also, check this `C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\``

Comment: You can be pretty sure that you have a dependency on 4.0 with this exception message.  Standard failure mode is starting the project targeting 4.0 and then downgrading to 3.5.  Which has a knack for not updating *some* references.  The kind that are hard to find are in a .resx file.  Including ones that are already embedded as a resource in an assembly that you didn't build.

Comment: Here are LinqtoTwitter dependencies : [http://i.imgur.com/8sJCMSE.jpg](http://i.imgur.com/8sJCMSE.jpg)

Hans Passant , I know what you are saying, but If there is a .Net 4.0 dependency , how it works on a clean system with only .NET 3.5 installed? That confuse me. I can not see that error at all. But it happens on customer machine.

Comment: Did you see what I say? - your customer [may be] reporting an error that doesn't belong to your app. Clear that out

Comment: Yea, i saw that! That is not possible, they just sent me the log file which belongs to my software ;)